# git and removing files

Tags: git

Is the only way to remove files from a working tree, have git notice it and incorporate that change in future HEADs is to use `git rm`?
I just want to be sure. I've been using regular bash 'rm' for a bit now and git is never picking up on those file/dir deletions and it was bugging me why it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you have to use `git rm` to remove them from the source control, you can see the [man](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) page for more details.

Answer (score 6):

`git rm` is the usual way but there are other ways. If you use `git add -u` or `git commit -a` to stage all changes to currently tracked files then the deletion action for tracked files which have been removed will be correctly staged. `git add -A` will also notice deleted files.

Answer (score 3):

`git commit -a` would automatically pick up file deletions.