# What is the name for this git state I have (removed without rm, but still in remote, can't be downloaded)

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble googling the solution to this problem by describing the symptoms, so I'm assuming I'm not using the correct terminology.  Here's what I did:

1. Trying to reorganize my git file structure a little, I moved fileA from repo-root/ into repo-root/subfolder/ in nautilus.
2. $ git add .
3. $ git commit -m "Just moving files"
4. $ git push

Looking at github, I see the file is now located in both repo-root/ and repo-root/subfolder.  Oh no, I only want one copy in the repo!  No problem, I can pull the repo again and `git rm` the file in repo-root/.

\5. $ git pull
Already up to date

Uh oh.

The file doesn't exist in that location on my local machine, so `git rm fileA` in repo-root/ doesn't see the file when I tab over. I also can't seem to pull it down without maybe entirely re-cloning again?  What is the name of the state my repo mismatch is in, and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate. Just use `git rm` to remove files (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767999/git-and-removing-files)? bash completion won't work in that case.
Also you can use `git checkout filename` to restore file (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407379/how-to-bring-back-removed-file).

Comment: I understand this has the same answer as probably a thousand other git questions---but it's a different question.  I want to know the /name/ of the condition I'm in.  If I google "git and removing files" I still don't get the link you posted, even though that's the title.  Also, there are a thousand other issues related to "removing files" that also pop up for a query that general.

Comment: condition... hmm. "Modified working tree" probably that is. You just deleted a file from your working tree. That is all. `git status` should report to your that file as deleted and suggests to add it or restore, with commands examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, seems solution is...

1. `git rm fileA` still works, even though there is no longer a local copy to auto-complete---you have to know the name of the file.  This worked for me, but could be trouble if you had a large number of files to remove.
2. `git add -u` will delete stuff staged for deletion, and was probably the right choice?
3. In the future, using `git commit -am "my message"` could help, because `commit -a` captures deletions, where `add .` doesn't.
4. Saw this one at commandlinefu `git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)` I didn't try it, but looks clever.

Anyhow, I still don't really know what the name of this is, so I'm not considering this an answer.  Unindexed-deletions?  Detatched deletion?  Unstaged deletions?

Comment: I think it's "Modified working tree". There is no significant difference between this state and if you just edited some files.

Comment: Always do a `git status`before committing and pushing. If you would have done that, you could have caught the problem at an earlier stage. `git rm --cache path/to/file` will remove the deleted file from git cache.

Comment: Would it be correct to say something like, "You have staged (git add .) and committed (git commit) your additions, but have not staged (git add -u) and therefore, not committed your deletions?"  Alex, I'd accept your comment as an answer unless someone else comes through knowing a magical name for my mistake here.  =)

Comment: @alexvasi, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  Else I'll accept this answer, pointing out your comment?